# How to resolve No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I am getting an error when accessing camera the error is

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) }

this is where the error occurs

```
   try {
        val intent = Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
   } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.d("errorCamera", "${exception}")
        exception.printStackTrace()
   }
```

Min and target sdk version are

```
    minSdkVersion(23)
    targetSdkVersion(30)
```

Please suggest what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: Does this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435522/error-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-act-android-media-action-image-capture

Comment: Hello @AbhishekDutt I had a look at that, but was not sure what changes I need to make to my code

Comment: could you suggest what changes I need to make in my code which might resolve please

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you need to create an activity that will use the camera feature. And also add some permissions to the manifest file, like this for example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I'll leave you some resources here (hope it helps):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPHkhamDoyc&ab_channel=RahulPandey
- https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/Camera

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use this `Intent` for taking picture:

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

Comment: Hello I tried that but it did not work

Comment: @BRDroid Did you try on different devices?