# Facial Expression Detection App - button not working as desired, no error message

Tags: java, android

I have been working on a facial expression detection application using Android Studio with java and I have a few issues that I can't figure out.

Shortly, this application uses the camera to take a picture, display it in image_view and then run the facial expression detection. My main issue is that when I press the button nothing happens. I have added logs for my methods but only the ones inside the captureButton seem to appear in Logcat. Could you help me understand why is this happening? Why it doesn't capture the image and then display it in image_view?

This is my MainActivity.java file (I have a few more methods I did not attach that concern the camera view / usage / permission but I excluded them as I don't think they are relevant for this issue, that part works just fine)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 2;

    private Camera camera;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView resultTextView;
    private SurfaceView cameraPreview;
    private String currentPhotoPath;

    private MultiLayerNetwork neuralNetwork;
    private Bitmap imageBitmap;

    Button captureButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("onCreateMethod", "Start the onCreate method");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        captureButton = findViewById(R.id.capture_button);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        resultTextView = findViewById(R.id.result_text_view);
        cameraPreview = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);


        captureButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Check if the camera permission is granted
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Request the camera permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            } else {
                // Launch the camera activity

                Log.d("dispatchInButton", "Dispatch intent in button activity");
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                Log.d("Button", "Capture button clicked");
            }
        });

        // Load the neural network from the saved model
        try {
            neuralNetwork = ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork(getAssets().open("model.zip"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.newact.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Load the captured image from file path
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap capturedImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
           // Bitmap capturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
            Log.d("onActivRes", "begin onActivRes method");
            // Display the captured image
            imageView.setImageBitmap(capturedImage);

            // Recognize the facial expression
            FacialExpressionRecognizer recognizer = new FacialExpressionRecognizer(neuralNetwork);
            String expression = recognizer.recognize(capturedImage);

            // Display the recognized expression
            resultTextView.setText("Recognized expression: " + expression);

            // Save the image and recognized expression to Firebase Storage and Firestore
            FirebaseImageUploader.uploadImage(capturedImage, new FirebaseImageUploader.ImageUploadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onImageUploaded(String imageUrl) {
                    // Save the timestamp and recognized expression to Firestore
                    FirebaseExpressionSaver expressionSaver = new FirebaseExpressionSaver();
                    expressionSaver.saveExpression(expression, new FirebaseExpressionSaver.ExpressionSaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onExpressionSaved() {
                            // Expression save successful
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Expression saved to Firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onExpressionSaveFailed(Exception e) {
                            // Expression save failed
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to save expression to Firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            // Handle the successful saving of the expression here
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                            // Handle the failure of saving the expression here
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onImageUploadFailed(Exception e) {
                    // Image upload failed
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to upload image to Firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String imageUrl) {
                    // Handle the successful upload of the image here
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    // Handle the failure of the image upload here
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Please let me know your input on this!

I have been trying to use logs and see what works and where it stops, but I have come as far as this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GJF8.png)

Added the other methods in the MainActivity.java as well:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted, launch the camera activity
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        } else {
            // Permission denied, show a message or handle the case accordingly
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        setCameraDisplayOrientation();
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setCameraDisplayOrientation() {
    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }
    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate for the mirror effect
    } else {
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (camera != null) {
        // Stop the preview
        camera.stopPreview();

        // Set the camera parameters
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), width, height);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);

        // Rotate the camera preview by 0 degrees to the right
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

        // Apply the updated parameters
        camera.setParameters(parameters);

        // Start the preview
        camera.startPreview();
    }
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes, int width, int height) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) width / height;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for (Camera.Size size : supportedPreviewSizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;

        double diff = Math.abs(size.width - width) + Math.abs(size.height - height);
        if (diff < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = diff;
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : supportedPreviewSizes) {
            double diff = Math.abs(size.width - width) + Math.abs(size.height - height);
            if (diff < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = diff;
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: From your logs, it would seem that `takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` returns null since none of the log statements inside that `if` are output. So maybe there is no camera activity?

Comment: Hi @TylerV, for me the camera seemed to work just fine as it shows the activity in the emulator. I have updated the code for the methods I am using as well, also I have the permission in the manifest file <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435522/error-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-act-android-media-action-image-capture) relevant. Try removing that if-check on `takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` entirely and see what happens (if it fails, you will probably get a more useful error message).

Comment: @TylerV I tried to remove the if check and no errors were shown, nothing changed, same logs and all. :(

Comment: You have a log statement right after the "if" - it's not possible that it didn't output (the "Method createImageFile called" output). Update the code to show what you tried with the if-statement removed.

Comment: @TylerV I have update the code with the information provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435522/error-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-act-android-media-action-image-capture

Comment: But you haven't updated the logs, you still have the `resolveActivity` if-statement, and now `dispatchTakePictureIntent` doesn't have the log statements it had previously. A lot of things could cause it to not launch the intent (`resolveActivity` returning null, `photoFile` being null) - you need to figure out which of those it's hitting and ask a *specific* question about it.